# Saving switch button state isn't working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, toggle, togglebutton, android-togglebutton

I have a switch button for setting the sound of the app On and OFF, although it works normally but when I close the app then open it again.. the switch becomes `false` automatically..!? 
I've tried to save the last state via Shared Preference library [Hawk](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk) , but it not clear to me how to do it right.!?

That's when I've tried to use `Hawk`

```
  // ....

   bool soundON = Hawk.get("sound"); // NPE !!!

  if (soundON) {
    soundSwitch.setChecked(true);
    soundSwitch.setSelected(true);
  } else {
    soundSwitch.setChecked(false);
    soundSwitch.setSelected(false);
  }


soundSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
      isSoundEnabled = true;
      Hawk.put("sound", true);
     } else {
      isSoundEnabled = false;
    }
    Log.i("is checked sound", isChecked + "");
    }});
```

**UPDATE - Solution**

I used @Shrikant answer, but with just a small change.! I used `Boolean` instead `boolean` so I can check for `null` values which `Boolean` allows you to do since it can be `true` or `false` or `null` unlike `boolean` which can be either `true` or `false`.

Here's the code

```
Boolean isSound = Hawk.get("sound");

if (isSound == null) {
  // I want the sound to be ON by default so I set it to true
  soundSwitch.setChecked(true);
  soundSwitch.setSelected(true);
} else {
  soundSwitch.setChecked(isSound);
  soundSwitch.setSelected(isSound);
  Log.i("Sound State > ", isSound + "");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

In onCreate() init that Hawk

```
Hawk.init(context).build();
```

after this get your sound value from Hawk and set it to switch

```
boolean isSound = Hawk.get("some",false);
soundSwitch.setChecked(isSound);
soundSwitch.setSelected(isSound);
```

there is not to check boolean by if else

```
soundSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            Log.i("is checked sound", isChecked + "");
            Hawk.put("sound", isChecked);

        }
    });
```

I have used 2.0.1 version of Hawk.

Comment: it gives me npe error for this line  >  `boolean isSound = Hawk.get("sound");` & the error >                                                                              `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com...Settings}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference`

Comment: can you post error log as it shows in monitor and version of hawk your using

Comment: I'm using `hawk:2.0.1`  & no log showed coz the crash occurs once I launch the activity >  [screenshot](https://image.ibb.co/jRZ1Ha/zzzzzxzxz.png)

Comment: `isSound` will be `null` when the activity run for the first time, coz hawk value isn't saved yet..! so I surround it with `try and catch` so it can ignore the npe since it gonna happens one time only..! but the weird thing that happened is everytime i open the activity the npe occurs and I checked the hawk value and it was stored normally but `isSound` always equals `null` while located inside the `try` block...! any thoughts?

Comment: I solved it by using `Boolean` instead of `boolean` since `Boolean` can be `null` I could just check it using if statement ..! thanks so much man.
I'll add the final code in UPDATE.!

Answer (score 1):

In `onCreate()` method you have to check isSoundEnabled from shared preference whether you checked it from your local variable.

try this:

```
bool soundValue = Hawk.get("sound"); 
 if (soundValue) {
    soundSwitch.setChecked(true);
    soundSwitch.setSelected(true);
  } else {
    soundSwitch.setChecked(false);
    soundSwitch.setSelected(false);
  }
```

instead of :

```
 if (isSoundEnabled) {
    soundSwitch.setChecked(true);
    soundSwitch.setSelected(true);
  } else {
    soundSwitch.setChecked(false);
    soundSwitch.setSelected(false);
  }
```

in `onCreate()`

Comment: I don't get what you mean, can you elaborate more please.?

Comment: I did that..! the first code was before I used the shared preference and the second code is when i used that..! it gives me null pointer exception.
I will remove the first code to remove confusion

Comment: Please try with Hawk.put("sound", false); in else condition and let me know whether this library storing value properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should save the check state at the time of the setOnCheckedChangeListener call. And get the check state at the time of the onCreate call.

Comment: In the place where the data is stored and where the data is taken by onCreate , add the logcat print of the data to see if the value is the expected number.